# What is the proper usage of the Takbir?

Tags: arabic, takbir

What is the proper usage of the Takbir?

> Allahu Akbar

or

> Allah Hu Akbar

Comment: Are you asking how to pronounce it or how to write it in English?

Comment: @aasheq Both. As pronunciation is the basis for the written word in most cases.

Comment: After the Arabic site comes, this question has to be migrated there, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

First one is the right one, as made clear from Arabic

> Allāhu Akbar (الله أكبر)

The sound of "h" is just once, not twice

Answer (score 0):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In regard to your question that asked:

> What is the proper usage of the Takbir?
>
> Allahu Akbar or
>
> Allah Hu Akbar

The answer is the first one as @Hamza Islam mentioned it correctly. In truth it is the true pronunciation of that based on right Arabic language grammar. And it has not Tashdid as the mark put over a letter to indicate that it is to be pronounced hard as if it was two letters. Therefore it ought not to be pronounced hard, and actually there is just a "h"; accordingly, the first one is true.